# Proving the function $f(x) = x^2 + ax + b$ is not injective. Does my proof make sense?

Tags: functions, solution-verification, proof-writing

The question I’ve been working on is:
Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is not injective.

Here's what I've come up with. I'm hoping someone can tell me if I messed up somewhere. (I'm not sure whether the last part is clear enough, or whether makes sense or not). Also this isn't for a homework assignment--this is just for me.

$\text{Let } m,n\in\mathbb{R} \text{ such that } f(m) = f(n).$
We consider two cases:

Case 1: $a=0.$ Then, substituting, we have
$$ m^2 +b=n^2+b\\m^2=n^2\\\text{either }m=n \text{ or }m=-n$$
Therefore, we can have $f(n)=f(-n) \text{ but } n\neq -n$. Therefore, $f$ is not injective.

Case 2: $a\neq0.$ Then, we have
$$m^2+am+b=n^2+an+b\\m^2+am=n^2+an\\
m^2-n^2=a(n-m)\\(m+n)(m-n)=a(n-m)\\(1/a)(m+n)(m-n)=(n-m)\\-(1/a)(m+n)(m-n)=(m-n)$$
This means that either $m=n$  , or,   $-(1/a)(m+n)=1$. We will consider the latter equation. Or, in other words, $a=-(m+n)$. Consequently, $n=-m-a$. Therefore it is possible for $m\neq n$. Thus, $f$ is not injective.

Comment: You don't need subcases, $\,m+n=-a\,$ is the same as $\,m=-n\,$ when $\,a=0\,$. And it's enough to give one counterexample to disprove injectivity, for example $\,f\left(-\frac{a}{2}-1\right)=f\left(-\frac{a}{2}+1\right)\,$.

Comment: I just thought I would need a subcase where a != 0 because I ended up dividing by a. Thanks for the advice about the counterexample as well

Comment: You did not need to divide by $a$, and you don't actually use that since you multiply by $a$ at the very end to transform $-(1/a)(m+n)=1$ back into $a=-(m+n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Correct ideas are in your proof.  Your logical presentation is not right, though.  You shouldn't start the proof by saying "Let $m, n \in \mathbb R$ be such that $f(m) = f(n)$."  Rather, you need to argue that there exist two real numbers $m$ and $n$, such that $f(m) = f(n)$ but $m \neq n$.

Reverse engineer what you've written down to write a logically correct proof.